# How to modify this .htaccess to make only the pages preceded by /cn/ insecure (http)?

Tags: .htaccess

So right now my site looks like this:

`https://www.example.com`

It has many languages:

`https://www.example.com/es`

`https://www.example.com/hk`

(etc...)

How do I modify the following `.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
php_value upload_max_filesize    110M
php_value post_max_size          110M
```

so that only paegs with `/cn/` preceding them are insecure? (`http` instead of `https`) Example:

```
http://www.example.com/cn/
http://www.example.com/cn/subpage/
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# http requests anything other than /cn should become https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/cn(/.*)?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC,L,NE]

# https requests for /cn should become http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /cn(/.*)?\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,NC,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>

php_value upload_max_filesize    110M
php_value post_max_size          110M
```

Comment: First time I see `RewriteRule !...` +1

Comment: @anubhava I tried that. The page just keeps loading indefinitely.